# Get parameter from another application in ASP MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing an ASP MVC 3 application and I have a div which contains a page from a Python application. This Python application does a given service which creates a result that I want to use in my ASP MVC application.

How can I get this variable.

PS : The Python application uploads a video on dalymotion and the result is the URL of the uploaded file. The upload works fine but I cannot get the URL.

Any ideas ?

Thanks.

EDIT :

This is how I call the Python application from the ASP MVC application :

```
function uploadVideo(url, target) {
window.ht = setTimeout(function () {
    var div = document.getElementById(target);
    div.innerHTML = '<iframe frameborder="0" src="' + url + '" />';
}, 20);
}
```

And this is the form in the python application :

```
<form method="post" action="{{ upload_url|safe }}" onsubmit="openProgressBar(); return true;" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="uploadframe">
  <input type="file" name="file" />
  <input id="urlEmbedOC2" val="" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload"/>
</form>
```

I try to put the url inside that "urlEmbedOC2" input, but I can't access it from the ASP application.

EDIT :

I manage to do it like this : From the Python application, I use redirection to an action in my ASP application, I put the variable in a query string and then I can access it in my controller.

Comment: Please provide some code examples of what you have tried so far

Comment: After uploading the video to dailymotion store its url into a hidden field and then read it using jquery or any thing you want....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can let the Python application provide the data through a webservice with a URL which the ASP.NET application can consume.